# State outside of my useCallback is different to the one that is inside

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
  console.log('outside', currentPageNumber); // 0 then 3.

  const fetchMoreItems = useCallback(
    page => {
      const { from, to } = dateModifier(selectedMonth);
      const params = {
        from,
        to,
        limit: ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
        page: 3,
      };

      console.log('inside', currentPageNumber); // 0 

      if (selectedTab[ISSUES]) dispatchUserSuggestions({ ...params, type: 'issue' });
      if (selectedTab[SUGGESTIONS]) dispatchUserSuggestions({ ...params, type: 'suggestion' });
    },
    [dispatchUserSuggestions, selectedTab, selectedMonth],
  );
```

I need the `currentPageNumber` to be the new version of the state rather than the old one. I've tried adding it as a dependency to the useCallback but this puts me into an infinite loop.

Don't suppose anyone can tell what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should add the `currentPageNumber` as a dependency, and solve the infinite loop. The code that causes the loop doesn't appear in your example.

If you can't, you can use a `ref` as an escape hutch:

```
const currentRef = useRef();

console.log('outside', currentPageNumber);

useEffect(() => {
  currentRef.current = currentPageNumber;
}, [currentPageNumber]);

const fetchMoreItems = useCallback(
  page => {
    const { from, to } = dateModifier(selectedMonth);
    const params = {
      from,
      to,
      limit: ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
      page: 3,
    };

    console.log('inside', currentRef.current);

    if (selectedTab[ISSUES]) dispatchUserSuggestions({ ...params, type: 'issue' });
    if (selectedTab[SUGGESTIONS]) dispatchUserSuggestions({ ...params, type: 'suggestion' });
  },
  [dispatchUserSuggestions, selectedTab, selectedMonth],
);
```

Comment: You are a legend.